# Transfer longpress from one android view to another, without releasing finger

Tags: android, view, gesture

We have a longpress detection on a button. When detected, the view should be dismissed (back to the game view) and the object chosen with the button shall be at the coordinates of the longpress. That's the easy part, the hard part is to then change the coordinates with the finger, without releasing it.

Okay so i'm trying to reformulate this: We have two views displayed on top of eachother. What we want is a longclick detected in the top view, to then dismiss the top view, and without releasing the finger, get touchevents in the bottom view.

This is our class gameView: (this code contains a lot of code unneccesay for the problem)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mode = DRAG;
            //We assign the current X and Y coordinate of the finger to startX and startY minus the previously translated
            //amount for each coordinates This works even when we are translating the first time because the initial
            //values for these two variables is zero.               
            startX = event.getX() - previousTranslateX;
            startY = event.getY() - previousTranslateY;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:               
            translateX = event.getX() - startX;
            translateY = event.getY() - startY;

            gestureHandler.setTranslation(translateX, translateY);

            //We cannot use startX and startY directly because we have adjusted their values using the previous translation values. 
            //This is why we need to add those values to startX and startY so that we can get the actual coordinates of the finger.
            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.getX() - (startX + previousTranslateX), 2) + 
                                        Math.pow(event.getY() - (startY + previousTranslateY), 2)
                                       );

            if(distance > 0) {
               dragged = true;
            }               

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            mode = ZOOM;

            scaleToX = event.getX();
            scaleToY = event.getY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            dragged = false;

            //All fingers went up, so let's save the value of translateX and translateY into previousTranslateX and 
            //previousTranslate           
            previousTranslateX = translateX;
            previousTranslateY = translateY;

            int x = (int)((-translateX/scaleFactorX)+(event.getX()/this.scaleFactorX));
            int y = (int)((-translateY/scaleFactorY)+(event.getY()/this.scaleFactorY));

            map.click(getContext(), x, y);


            for(CastleTile castleTile : map.getCastleTiles()) {

                if(castleTile.getRect().contains((int)((-translateX/scaleFactorX)+(event.getX()/this.scaleFactorX)), (int)((-translateY/scaleFactorY)+(event.getY()/this.scaleFactorY)))){
                    Log.d("Castle to your service", "Boes");

                    castleSettings.show();
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = DRAG;

            //This is not strictly necessary; we save the value of translateX and translateY into previousTranslateX
            //and previousTranslateY when the second finger goes up
            previousTranslateX = translateX;
            previousTranslateY = translateY;
            break;       
    }

    detector.onTouchEvent(event);

    //We redraw the canvas only in the following cases:
    //
    // o The mode is ZOOM 
    //        OR
    // o The mode is DRAG and the scale factor is not equal to 1 (meaning we have zoomed) and dragged is
    //   set to true (meaning the finger has actually moved)
    if ((mode == DRAG && scaleFactorX != 1f && scaleFactorY != 1f && dragged) || mode == ZOOM) {
        invalidate();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    castleSettings.dismiss();
    return true;
}
```

And this is the gestureHandler:

```
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
    map.longClick(context, (int)((-translateX/scaleFactorX)+(event.getX()/this.scaleFactorX)), (int)((-translateY/scaleFactorY)+(event.getY()/this.scaleFactorY)));
}
```

Sorry for eventual lack of information or bad explaination :)